# How to properly set up Ubuntu 20.04 to deploy a node.js app without caching issues?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu

I have launched my first node.js app using express.js for the backend and react.js for the frontend. I have it deployed as a background service on a VM with Ubuntu 20.04. The app itself is pretty simple. It makes an API call, gets the latest data and displays it to the enduser in a web browser interface. I initially deployed it on a free Heroku account, where it works fine and always display the latest info from the API call. But when I deployed it on a private VM with Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed that it does not show the latest API info anymore, i.e. it makes the initial API call during npm start and then probably caches it on the server. So, if I come to the app the next day, all the data is from yesterday. To see the latest data, I have to kill the background service on Ubuntu and then do "npm start", which starts the server and makes the API call. I then see the latest data in the browser. This is my first time working with all this technology, so if you have had a similar issue with deploying on Ubuntu, please let me know how I can fix it.

Here is my package.json "scripts":

```js
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node server/server.js --ignore public/",
    "build": "babel server --out-dir dist",
    "start": "node dist/server.js &",
    "dev": "webpack -w --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production"
  }
```

Here is my server.js code:

```js
import config, { nodeEnv, logStars } from "./config";
import apiRouter from "./api";
import sassMiddleware from "node-sass-middleware";
import path from "path";
import AMdataPullDone from "./AMdataPullDone";

import express from "express";
const server = express();

server.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, "sass"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  })
);

server.set("view engine", "ejs");

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  AMdataPullDone.then(({ initialMarkup, initialData }) => {
    res.render("index", {
      initialMarkup,
      initialData,
    });
  }).catch(console.error);
});

server.use("/api", apiRouter);
server.use(express.static("public"));

server.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
  console.info("Express listening on port ", config.serverUrl);
});
```

And here is my index.js file with the reach App:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <App initialData={window.initialData} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

AMdataPullDone.js code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "./src/components/App";
import generateToken from "./utils/generateToken";
import serverGetAMData from "./serverGetAMData";

const AMdataPullDone = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  generateToken()
    .then(({ access_token }) => {
      serverGetAMData(
        access_token,
        "URL_to_external_API"
      )
        .then((segResult) => {
          const allData = {
            initialMarkup: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <App initialData={segResult} />
            ),
            initialData: segResult,
          };
          return resolve(allData);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return reject(err.response);
        });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

export default AMdataPullDone;
```

serverGetAMData.js code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import config from "./config";

const serverGetAMData = async (access_token, apiUrl) => {
  const folders = [];
  
  await axios
    .get(apiUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        "x-api-key": config.AM_IMS_client_id,
        "x-gw-ims-org-id": config.org_id,
      }
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      folders.push(...resp.data);
      //return resp.data;
    })
    .catch(console.error);

  return folders;
  
};
export default serverGetAMData;
```

Comment: There is apparently caching going on somewhere.  I can't tell from your description whether it's browser caching, server-side caching of browser requests or back-end caching in your "background job".  You need to figure out which it is because each leads to different solutions.  If it's your back-end doing the caching, then we'd have to see that specific back-end code (where the caching is occurring) to be able to offer ideas on how to change/fix it.  Note that questions here that don't show any relevant code often have trouble getting answers because we're left to "guess" what might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @jfriend00. I have added more detail and code examples of my app. So, hopefully someone had a similar scenario.

Comment: What is the module `AMdataPullDone()` and where does it come from?  Does it do caching?  Can you post a link to that module's documentation and/or code?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I have added my code for AMdataPullDone(). It basically makes a call to an API to get the info. I am not setting any caching anywhere in the app specifically.

Comment: And, what is `serverGetAMData()`?  I'm trying to trace your code all the way to an actual http request to see where caching might be happening.  FYI, `AMdataPullDone()` is a promise anti-pattern as you're wrapping an existing promise in another promise and failing to handling all possible error paths (which is a common issue when you unnecessarily wrap an existing promise in another).  You can just return the main promise you already have without wrapping it in another promise and just chain your nested calls so the promises link.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added my code for serverGetAMData(). I have a feeling that the problem might be on the Ubuntu side because if I login into the VM and do “ps aux | grep node” to get the process id, then “kill [process id]”, then do npm start to spin up the server.js file, it makes the fresh call to the api and displays the lates data from the API. I tried to do a cron job in crontab to automatically kill the process and restart it again, but no luck so far and this solution seems not ideal. I come from the world of PHP, so all this is very new to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 - your suggestions about caching gave me an idea. I have deployed the same app code to a free Heroku and everything works fine there, so it must be a problem with my Ubuntu setup. The only difference, I did not add "&" in "node dist/server.js &" for Heroku, since it was not needed there. I will keep reading on how to properly deploy apps on Ubuntu VMs, since I have to use it.